# Custom validation filter on yii2

Tags: yii2

I need to filter data that come from hmtl form from html tags, quotes etc.

It seems that I need to write my own filter callback function according to http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filtervalidator.html . I got these rules in my model:

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'email', 'phone',], 'required'],
            [['course'], 'string',],
            [['name', 'email', 'phone',], 'string', 'max'=>250],
            ['email', 'email'],
            [['name', 'email', 'phone'], function($value){
                return trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($value), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
            }],

        ];
    }
```

Last rule is my own filter that i added. But it is not working. Tags, spaces, qoutes don't remove from and this filter is not even running. How to achieve what i want and what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are adding validator wrong. If you want to use `FilterValidator` (which you mentioned in your question) and not inline validator, change your code like this:

```
[['name', 'email', 'phone'], 'filter', 'filter' => function($value) {
    return trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($value), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
}],
```

`['name', 'email', 'phone']` - validated attributes.

`filter` - validator short name. See full list of compliances [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html).

The next elements are parameters that will be passed to this validator. In this case we specified [filter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filtervalidator.html#$filter-detail) parameter.

See full list of available parameters in official documentation to specific validator.